# Laravel View Composer "Use of undefined constant"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

been looking all evening and it all seems so easy and simple but just won't work!

Just starting out and trying to get a variable into a view.

Whatever i do, i can't seem to read it.

routes.php:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('dashboard');
});

View::composer('dashboard', function($view) {
    $view->with('links', "something");
});
```

dashboard.blade.php:

```
@extends('base_view')

@section('content')
    All the stuff!
    {{links}}
@stop
```

base_view.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Laravel PHP Framework</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>TeamPro</div>
    <div>@yield('content')</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me i'm just doing something stupid!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `$links`, not `links`:

```
@section('content')
    All the stuff!
    {{ $links }}
@stop
```

Every variable in PHP should be preceded by a `$` sign. If there's no `$`, PHP treats it as a constant.

Comment: I am an idiot! That dollar sign has robbed me of part of my life!

Comment: @RykWaters - We've all been there.

Comment: ARGH I did this as well! Even read this, dismissed it, then came back and realised I'd done it.

Comment: @RykWaters Haha! Same here. Working with Angular Views and Blade messes it up.

Answer (score 5):

It's just a simple syntax issue, everything you send to a view is a php variable so still needs to be referenced with the `$`

In your view, you are referencing `links` without the dollar sign.

If you update it to:

```
{{ $links }}
```

You'll be A-OK